# Tips for first time Dungeon Master

Tags: game-recommendation

I'm a first time dungeons and dragons dungeon master. I've played the game only a couple of times before. Basically I am using the starter set that I got at the bookstore. Characters are premade as well as mission. So far it's working out fine because all of the adventurers are first time players.
   I guess my question is does anybody have any advice on how to enhance gameplay further? I do a couple things like award some random loot every now and then for good ideas the group or solo players come up with.
   Any tips would be great.
Thanks.